# Socket Java Application - Html site operated by the client class

Tags: java, sockets

I am making a java program which uses a Socket to connect. I wrote a standard server and client application.

The problem is that I have to log in (by providing the username and password) through the client's application. When I log in, I can’t turn on my webpage and I don’t know how to do it.

By standard server and client application I mean this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EchoServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
ServerSocket echoServer = null;
Socket clientSocket = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
   echoServer = new ServerSocket(9999);
}
catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e);
   System.exit(1);
}
try {
   clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
   InetAddress address = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
   int port = clientSocket.getPort();
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
   String line;
   while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
out.println(line); 
   }
   in.close();
   out.close();
   clientSocket.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
echoServer.close();
    }
}
```

and the client:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Socket echoSocket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
String hostname = "localhost";
if(args.length > 0) hostname=args[0];
try {
   echoSocket = new Socket(hostname, 9999);
   out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   System.exit(1);
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.exit(1);
}

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String userInput;
while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
   out.println(userInput);
   System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
}
out.close();
in.close();
stdIn.close();
echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I know that this code doesn’t transfer html source file a web browser, but it does in my code.

How to connect with a web browser to the server after connecting through the client's server?

Comment: Further, unless there's some HTTP bits that we aren't seeing here, there's no web browser involved anywhere in the code...

Comment: @Charles I wrote below that this codes don’t transfer html source file a web browser, but it does in my code.